# VBA connection string to SQL Server Express 2017

Tags: vba, connection-string, sql-server-express, mdf

My environment is Windows 10 (PCA), SQL Server Express 2017, and I'm using VBA.

I'm trying to do something really simple. Since I can't use SQL Server CE, I'm using SQL Server Express 2017. I simply want to create an MDF file I can use on another Windows 10 computer (PCB) that is also running SQL Server Express 2017 and have my VBA code open up the database.

So I went about this task by creating a database in SQL Server Mgt Studio. It put the .mdf file in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA".

If I stop the service "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)", I can copy out the .mdf and log file to another location. Eventually I want to access the file from a remote computer, but just trying to get this seemingly simple task done.

The problem is I can't open up the file using ADODB on another computer, even after I copy it from PCA to PCB. Heck, I can't even open it up on the same computer I created it on (PCA) using the VBA code below! Maybe it's my connection string?

Everyone can have access to it, and I plan on accessing it through password and also encrypting the file,  but for now I'll take just opening it!

I've tried all these connection strings, but I'm a bit confused on password protecting the file in SSE?

```
Set dbConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbConn.Mode = adModeShareDenyNone
dbConn.CursorLocation = adUseServer

sDBFile = "\\PCB\c$\programdata\company\product\test.mdf"

'   SQL Express 2017
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;"
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;AttachDbFilename=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Database=test;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Initial Catalog=test;User Instance=True; "
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;AttachDbFilename=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;Initial Catalog=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;Initial Catalog=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;User ID=domain\user1;Password=password;Database=" & Chr$(34) & Chr$(34) & ";"
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;Initial Catalog=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;User ID=domain\user1;Password=password;Database=test;"
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;Initial Catalog=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";User ID=domain\user1;Password=password;"

sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Data Source=M10;Initial Catalog=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
sConnectionString = "Data Source=M10;Initial Catalog=test.sdf;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"

sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Data Source=M10;AttachDbFilename=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;"
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=M10;AttachDbFilename=" & Chr$(34) & sDBFile & Chr$(34) & ";Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
sConnectionString = "Data Source=M10;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

dbConn.ConnectionString = sConnectionString

dbConn.Open
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly the problem is because you explained too much that I lost the thread, but there are things you have to try first and then see what happens, 1-do NOT name any file `test`, it is a bad idea and sometimes you get nothing like an error or sth, but you don't get any result too so rename the file and try again 2-are you sure the address is valid? when you copy paste the address for `sDBFile` in the address bar of the file explorer does file explorer on windows takes you there?

Comment: also, remove your password from the SQL database and then edit this connection string and try it `Private Const sCONNECTION_STRING As String = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=SLI0115\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TMS;Trusted_Connection=yes;"`

Comment: I just can't open the .mdf file. Just trying on PCA, then migrate to PCB. No, I don't use 'test' or 'password', just an example.

Comment: Yes, the .mdf file exists and explorer finds it

Comment: did you try the connection string I gave you? just edit it based on your database

Comment: So I successfully got this working. Here is my connection string: sConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=" & sComputer & ";AttachDbFilename=\\" & sDBFile & ";Database=test;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Comment: I got local and remote working. To get it, I think I just needed to understand how SQL Server attaches databases. I attached a local copy of the test.mdf file on each server. Using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) really helped. First, I RDP'ed into the remote server. Once in, I enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server. I then attached the test.mdf database file using SSMS. Back on my local computer, I loaded the local copy of test.MDF into SSMS. Then, in my VB6 code, I connected successfully to the local DB.

Comment: To connect to the remote sql server, I used the same connection string, EXCEPT I did not use "Database=test;". This also worked perfectly. Setting the "Database=test;" only should be enabled if it's the local PC if that database is already attached to SQL Server on the local PC.